A horror movie in which cockroaches evolve into monsters
I have seen this movie back in early 90s. English speaking (American). Color.
It starts with a waitress or a waiter working in a diner, and noticing that cockroaches have infested the place, and she/he tries their best to get rid of them.
There is a father and a daughter, at some point, the father transforms into a monstrous cockroach with fangs and claws. (He was doomed to transform as he gradually gets sicker before he transforms. He might have been bitten by one of the little cockroaches).
At one scene, a cat is put inside a glass box and something is introduced inside the box (maybe a cockroach, or maybe a little piece of meat, I can't remember). But we see the cat getting transformed into a monstrous thing and eventually dies (or gets killed by the one making the experiment).
I think the cause of the cockroach behavior is some toxic waste issue but I am not too sure about it.
After her monstrous father is killed, the daughter is saved by a man who takes her to his place. 
We later find out that the waiter/waitress at the diner is dead trying to eliminate the cockroach infestation. Maybe they used too much pesticide, or maybe the room temperature was too cold for cockroach and human alike. 
That's all I can remember.

Sounds like The Nest from 1988.

The sheriff of this small island town called North Port has a roach problem in his house. According to the local exterminator Homer (played by Stephen Davies), it turns out the whole town is about to have a BIG roach problem. Pets, and then people, begin to disappear.

A cat in a glass box is transformed into a monstrous hybrid by the mutant roaches, and this also happens to a human (the father of one of the female characters). Here are the death scenes (Warning: Gory):



